# Bigquery error when calling procedure from C#

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm trying out the new Procedures in BigQuery. I've 3 procedures

```
PROC1
BEGIN 
CREATE TEMP TABLE tempTab AS
SELECT DISTINCT station_id, name FROM `powerful-decker-249310.Views.Stations` LIMIT 1000;
END

PROC2
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM tempTab;
END

PROC3
BEGIN 
CALL `powerful-decker-249310.Procedures.PROC1`();
CALL `powerful-decker-249310.Procedures.PROC2`();
END
```

Using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2, I'm trying to execute `CALL`powerful-decker-249310.Procedures.PROC3`();

```
var resultsOptions = new GetQueryResultsOptions { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, Timeout, 0) };
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions{ UseLegacySql = false  };
queryOptions.DestinationTable = bqClient.GetTable("powerful-decker-249310","Tables", "StationsTmp").Reference;

results = bqClient.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters: null, queryOptions: queryOptions, resultsOptions: resultsOptions);
```

It's throwing an exception

> configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts

If I comment out queryOptions.DestinationTable, it throws

> Query doesn't have a destination table'

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does a simple `call PROC3()` from regular query window in BQ UI or bq command line work?

Comment: Yes. it works in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue by moving to the beta version of the driver. But I faced another issue. The driver returns only the final result set even if the wrapper procedure returns multiple result sets. 
I raised an issue with Google and they acknowledged that it is an issue with the underlying API and have asked to raise a feature request. 
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/3772

Answer (score 0):

A script is always able to output multiple result set, which is why setting single destination table doesn't work.

If you have full control over your procedure, you can output all your datasets to persistent table and delete them afterwards or make them short-lived (by setting expiration_timestamp) and leave them alone.